# Cron expression for set of days in azure function app

Tags: cron, azure-functions

I want to trigger a timer function in Azure between two sets of days 1-5, 25-30. How do I set the cron expression for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to trigger a timer function in Azure between two sets of days 1-5, 25-30. How do I set the cron expression for this.

We have the best tool to get the CRON Expressions for our required timers/sets along with their explanation.

**The following code triggers between 1-5 and 25-30 in the month.**

[image]

**CRON Expression Explanation:**

[image]

For more information, please refer this [CRON Expression Generator Tool](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_1-5,25-30_*_*).

Comment: This is not working with Azure App Services. This is missing the seconds part.

Comment: CRON expression can be 5 or 6 digit @PawanPillai

Comment: How would you mention seconds in your format?